# Get Symbols On Win32 Button Control

Tags: winapi, button, controls, calculator, symbols

I'm a noob to C++ / Win32 programming and I'm working on a basic calculator ( using windows calculator as a reference ). I was wondering how I'd be able to get a check mark ( square root ) to appear on one of the buttons, as well as the plus over the minus symbol ( negative to positive number ) as well. Would I have to create images for them or is there a simpler way? Also the arrow would be nice to that way I'm not using "<=" haha. :)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The easy way is to open 'Character Map' on Windows (type that into the Help). (or use windows run utility [Win_Key+R] and type "charmap" and press ok)  You can find most characters you may want as 16  bit codes in some font or other. Then you just set the font for the button (SetFont API) and write the character code to it.
[image: Charmap]

You can paint a button any way you like by using its owner-draw style. That means you get to paint the whole thing in WM_DRAWITEM.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Unicode Build
// -------------

HWND hWndButtonSquareRoot;
[...]
SetWindowText( hWndButtonSquareRoot, L"\u221A" );

HWND hWndButtonPlusMinus;
[...]
SetWindowText( hWndButtonPlusMinus, L"\u00B1" );
```

If you do no want to switch to an UNICODE build, you have to create a UNICODE button using the UNICODE version of the API.

```
CreateWindowW( L"Button",  L"\u221A", [...]
```

Comment: I tried doing it that way and instead of the square root symbol, i get a forward arrow followed by a double quote. --- Weird.. I also can't put the L in front of "\u221A" or it gives me an error and won't compile. So instead i used: ( LPCSTR )L"\u221A" to convert it, which is what gives me what I'm getting.

Comment: You can't make an ANSI "Button" Window use UNICODE characters in it's default painting. Either switch to UNICODE for your project, or use the UNICODE version of the "Button" class. See updated answer. Sorry for delay.

Comment: @Vince Was the answer OK? It seems you don't accept answer very often  :-)